# MVC3 Pagination, items per page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, pagination

I have to implement pagination, number of Items per page and sorting for my MVC3 application.
In my view page I have a List of Items that is coming from the Model. I will be displaying a number of Items (defined by the user) each inside div, per each page. I'm not building a table.

I know that mvccontrib can build a table with paging, and not sure if that pagination can be styled at all, cause I have to style mine. What is a good approach to solve this?

Comment: Do you want to page the data on the client or server side?

Comment: jqGrid OR Knockout.js for the win...

Comment: @ShaneC: I'll mention ExtJs, since we are talking heavyweights. :)

Comment: I think I need a js component, since the the List I'm getting from the model already contains all records. An I need something I could style, since it's not a grid that I'm building, but rather a few divs side by side. Thank you.

Comment: Is there anything that will allow filtering along with paging ? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [PagedList (available as a nuget package)](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/PagedList). I found it really mvc-friendly so far.

Answer (score 1):

For server side paging, I use https://github.com/dvsspr/Halaman.
It is not documented yet, but it is very flexible and it uses fluent configuration.

One very simple use case for you.

@Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(AdminPageInfo page, SortInfo sort)
{
    PagedData<Account> model = accountRepository.Get().AsPagedData(page, sort);
    return (model.IsValid) ? View(model) : View("_Error");
}
```

@View

```
@model PagedData<Account>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Account Index";
}
<p>
    Total records: <strong>@Model.TotalRows</strong>
    <br />
    Total pages: <strong>@Model.TotalPages</strong>
    <br />
    Total records in current page: <strong>@Model.TotalRowsInPage</strong>
</p>
@Html.Pager(Model)
@Html.Sizer(Model) @* Page size changer helper =) *@
@*
Put a dot after the closing brace and you will see the available options.
*@

<h3>Sorter</h3>
<li>
    <ul>@(Html.SortLink<Account>(zz => zz.Id, Model, "User Id"))</ul>
    <ul>@(Html.SortLink<Account>(zz => zz.UserName, Model, "User Name"))</ul>
    <ul>@(Html.SortLink<Account>(zz => zz.FullName, Model, "Full Name"))</ul>
</li>
@foreach (var acc in Model) {
    <p>
        User name: @acc.UserName
        <br />
        Full name: @acc.FullName 
    </p>
}
```

That's it.
IMHO, the codebase can be hacked easily - just in case you want to implement hybrid paging.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a primarily client-side solution, I have never had any problems with jQuery's Tablesorter with Paginator plugin: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html

If you want to do this server side, the general approach is that you are going to cache the entire result-set server side*, then make (ajax or otherwise) calls to the server specifying which records are needed.  You'll pass a starting index and a number of records to return via querystring or form field (as well as some identifier for the query to make sure you're getting the right result set).

*As mrjoltcola points out in the comments, to cache or not to cache is a case by case issue, for larger result sets it may make more sense to make more db calls with smaller result sets. An alternate solution to the big-result-set problem is capping their result-set size and displaying a message advising them to make their query more specific if the threshold is exceeded.  I would advise going with your best judgement initially and optimizing ***if needed***.

Comment: All good except for the caching. We usually just pass the page range to the db, repeatedly, so the query uses it in its limiting clause (LIMIT, ROWNUM). Some result sets are way too large to cache, and even with small result sets, caching may be trouble with large user base. But still a good point, as there are some apps that actually require paging a result set at the time the query was run first. Caching then becomes a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

With plain HTML, you can use the Webgrid help in WebMatrix. It has paging support out of the box with MVC.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/hh288075.aspx

Otherwise, any of the major Javascript components (jqgrid, extjs, etc.) can do paging, all  depending on what your model source is. If you implement an AJAX datasource, then you need to pass the paging properties back and forth, so the paging can be done server-side efficiently (depending on your database backend).